# Paramer sent into in jsonpCallback function undefined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I'm executing this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: function (data) { alert("jsonp call-back: " + data); },
  success: function (a, b, c, d) { alert("call ok"); },
  error: function (a, b, c, d) { alert(a.state() + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d); }
});
```

The problem is that I get *data* to be *undefined* in *jsonpCallback* function. I also noticed that in the console, I've got an error message about a missing semicolon before statement. When I click the link on the right, I see the JSON structure I'm trying to get.

1. What did I miss in the call?
2. How can I get the requested content into my JS code?

The admin claims that the server is exposed as JSON data provider and it's supposed to work. I haven't verified that myself but I have to assume it's so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsonpCallback` option for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) lets you specify or generate the **name** of the function to use for the JSONP callback. It is not the actual callback. From the documentation:

> `jsonpCallback`
>
> Type: `String` or `Function()`
>
> **Specify the callback function *name*** for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is set to the return value of that function.

*(my emphasis)*

If you simply remove that option from your call, jQuery will auto-generate a unique name for you, and call your `success` function with the deserialized JSONP data.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've changed the *jsonpCallback* to *"myCallback"* and added that method (I prefer to have an own name there). Now I get no call to the method, only to *error* telling my *rejected*. Suggestions?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You're not allowed to use a function that exists. You can control the *name*, but jQuery creates (and later destroys) the actual function, because it needs to plumb it into the work it's doing for you; *you* get the data in the `success` handler. If you want to do this all yourself (specifying your own function, etc.), just define the function and then add a `script` tag using the relevant URL. That's all JSONP is.

Comment: Right. I managed to confuse myself. Now I'm back at the original problem. I'm getting *rejected* and, because of that, *parsererror customJsonpCallback was not called*. What can I do on the client side to resolve it? Or do I have to ask the admin to do some magic server-side? What exactly?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Sounds like the response isn't JSONP, or it's not honoring the query string parameter for the name of the callback. I'd watch the Network tab in the developer tools of your browser, you'll probably see the response come back either not in JSONP form at all, or using the wrong function name.

Comment: According to the tab. a GET is executed (including the prefixed callback method name) of type json and in the reply, I can see the data. As far I can see, it's a valid JSON. It says *sytax error: missing semicolon before statement* but that's not it, right? More suggestions? I'm drawing a blank here...

Comment: @KonradViltersten: JSONP and JSON are very different things. A simple JSONP response would look like this: `yourFunctionName({data:"here"})` or `yourFunctionName({"data":"here"})` whereas in JSON it would be `{"data":"here"}`. So it's important that both ends agree on what the format will be.

Comment: So, by other words, in order to use cross domain call and JSONP, I need to change something on the server that feeds the stuff, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Yes, cross-domain support requires changing the server side of things, whether you use JSONP or CORS.